# Tweets from past periods

Tags: twitter, streaming

I need to use Python to download tweets (probably in the order of the tens of thousands) from past periods. Should I use the streaming API? Do you have any reference to suggest? Thanks

Comment: Also can be achieved with Gnip, which is also a paid service. http://gnip.com/products/historical/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming API do not deal with **past** periods, you should use [search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). Be aware of fact that it [returns up to 3200 tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8021). Also, from the docs

> Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all
>   Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.

For the reference, list libraries to deal with API can be found [there](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).

Comment: thanks for the clarification! Do you know what's the way to overcome the 3200 tweets limitation?

Comment: not with twitter api. something can be done with topsy http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57601209-93/topsy-indexes-entire-tweet-history-for-search-analysis/, but they are paid service http://api.topsy.com/doc/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Like they said, you cannot retrieve past tweets from their streaming API. You can try to look for free datasets like these ones (but it is quite difficult that the dataset that you find fits your needs):

http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/twitter-census-developer-tools-mapping-from-twitter-user-search-

http://www.sananalytics.com/lab/twitter-sentiment/