# Can't find a method for gaining access to tweets from past year?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to access tweets from the past year (dating as far back as possible). I've done a lot of research and what I have found is:

1. Referencing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619610/tweets-from-past-periods), The Twitter API will only return up to 3200 tweets. Streams are obviously not going to work, and GET requests have strict limits. I've been able to grab some data using Tweepy, but not nearly enough results that I am looking for.
2. Also from the above page, Topsy was a service that might have been helpful. However, it has since shut down by Apple.
3. There seem to be a couple of 'big data' sites, that might be able to help, but I was looking for a free method.

So, I'm not sure what to do now. Is there any way to get a large amount (+1GB) of tweets, dating as far back as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. The oldest you can get with the Search API is around 7 days.

Look at the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24214189/2297475). There seems to be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for accessing older tweets  https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python
For example

```
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('europe refugees').setSince("2015-05-01").setUntil("2015-09-30").setMaxTweets(10)
tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[0]

print tweet.text
```

Read the documentation in the page for more examples.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference. Also, please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38990113/4174897) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: @Kyll The link was so good that it is self-explantory. However, I have modified the answer to add an example.

Comment: Do try to avoid posting multiple, highly similar answers all suggesting a library. It may appear as unsolicited promotion to the community.